# Laravel excel, update rows after save in DB

Tags: php, excel, maatwebsite-excel

Project in Laravel (9), and PHP (8.1).

I want to import an excel file and use `maatwebsite/excel` (3.1) package.

I can import a file, and save the file into the model, like this:

import class:

```
class BankTransfersHistoryImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithValidation, WithBatchInserts
{
    use Importable;

    private $rows;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->rows = collect();
    }

/**
 * @param array $row
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
 */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        $bankTransferHistory = new BankTransfersHistory([    
            'loanId' => $row['loanId'],
            'actionDate' => transformDate($row['actionDate']),
            'worth' => $row['worth'],
            .
            .
        ]);

        $this->rows->push($bankTransferHistory);
        return $bankTransferHistory;
    }

    /**
     * Returns Imported Data
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function getImportedData(): \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [ 
            '*.loanId' => ['required', 'numeric'],
            ... some roles ...
        ];
    }
}
```

controller:

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx',
        ]);

        $file = $request->file('file');

        $import = new BankTransfersHistoryImport;

        try {
            // date validation
            $collection = $import->toCollection($file);
            ... some validation about the date ...

            $import->import($file);
            $getImportedData = import->getImportedData();
            ... check and update rows ...

            return [
                "message" => some message,
                "data" => [
                    some data
                ],
            ];

        } catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException$e) {
            $failures = $e->failures();

            foreach ($failures as $failure) {
                $failure->row(); // row that went wrong
                $failure->attribute(); // either heading key (if using heading row concern) or column index
                $failure->errors(); // Actual error messages from Laravel validator
                $failure->values(); // The values of the row that has failed.
            }
            return $failures;
      }
```

### **My question is:**

If I can get the response of the file after saving the data, that will give me the data with the id of the row that was saved.

In some cases, I will have to update a row. That's why I would like to get the ID.

Now, in the check and update rows section, I update row by `loanId` + `actionDate`. I want it to be done by only ID.

---

something like this:

code:
`$getImportedData = import->getImportedData();`

data will be like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "loanId": 21001,
        "actionDate": "2020-01-02T00:00:00.000000Z",
        "worth": 2997.09,
        "offerId": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "loanId": 21002,
        "actionDate": "2020-01-02T00:00:00.000000Z",
        "worth": 3000,
        "offerId": 10,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

### The solution to my problem.

To save the information and get the ID of each saved row, I did a few things.

#### I changed my import class.

- First I changed the create from `ToModel` to `ToCollection`
- I deleted `WithBatchInserts` because this method does not work with `ToCollection`.

#### Next, I called the `getImportedData` function.

That's how I got all the rows I create in the DB with their ID.

---

##### This solved the problem for me to get the information saved with the ID of each line, and perform validation + update if necessary.

---

The code is below.

A small note:

- I changed the word `rows` to `data` in the `getImportedData' function.
- I save all the files in the system.

##### import class:

```
class BankTransfersHistoryImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow, WithValidation
{
    use Importable;

    private $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data = collect();
    }

/**
 * @param array $row
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
 */
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $bankTransferHistory = BankTransfersHistory::create([
                'loanId' => $row['loanId'],
                'actionDate' => transformDate($row['actionDate']),
                'worth' => $row['worth'],
                .
                .
            ]);

            $this->data->push($bankTransferHistory);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns Imported Data
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function getImportedData(): \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [ 
            '*.loanId' => ['required', 'numeric'],
            ... some roles ...
        ];
    }
}
```

##### store controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required|mimes:xls,xlsx',
        ]);

        $file = $request->file('file');

        $import = new BankTransfersHistoryImport;

        try {
            // date validation
            $collection = $import->toCollection($file);
            ... some validation about the date ...

            // save the file in the system
            $fileName = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->storeAs('import bank transfers history', $fileName);

            $import->import($file);
            $importedData = $import->getImportedData(); // data after save in DB
            ... check and update rows ...

            return [
                "message" => some message,
                "data" => [
                    some data
                ],
            ];

        } catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException$e) {
            $failures = $e->failures();

            foreach ($failures as $failure) {
                $failure->row(); // row that went wrong
                $failure->attribute(); // either heading key (if using heading row concern) or column index
                $failure->errors(); // Actual error messages from Laravel validator
                $failure->values(); // The values of the row that has failed.
            }
            return $failures;
        }
    }
```